# nodejs send signals to child process does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am learning nodejs, and checked some examples about sending signals to child process, just as following codes, it is said "SIGINT" handler in child should be response, while I did not get any output.

```
// parent.js
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var child = spawn('node', ['child.js']);

child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log('data from child: ' + data);
});

child.kill('SIGINT');


// child.js
console.log('child calling');
process.on('SIGINT', function() {
  console.log('Received SIGINT signal');
});
```

When I am typing

> node parent.js

Why there is no output? even the "child calling" output in the child.js?

Hope anyone help me? Thanks.

In addition, I am not clear when the child.js is executed, at the time the execution of statement? Hope anyone can give a detail explanation? Thanks.

```
var child = spawn('node', ['child.js']);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first problem is that you spawn a child process and then *immediately* send it SIGINT.  Since the child process (probably) hasn't run at all yet, it hasn't registered for that signal and thus is killed by it.  The easiest way to get this working is to just put it in a `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  child.kill('SIGINT');
}, 100);
```

Now you'll see

```
data from child: child calling
```

and then it will exit.  But you're expecting the SIGINT message.  The problem this time is that the child process logs, registers for the signal, and then is done.  `node.js` will end if it finishes and isn't waiting on anything else.  Things it will wait on includes open sockets, `setTimeout`s, etc.  You need it to be doing something, though.  As a simple test, you can just add to `child.js`:

```
setInterval(function() {
  console.log('hey!');
}, 1000);
```

Or something like that.  Then you'll see the output you're expecting.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron Dufour. I tried your suggestion. It works.
While I am still not clear about your words "Things it will wait on includes open sockets, setTimeouts, etc."
You mean the setTimeouts in parent.js will open the child process sockets?
Could you please give a more detail explanaiton?

I also tried myself, I try to add "process.stdin.resume()" at the head of child.js, and add "process.stdin.end()" in the "SIGINT" handler, it also works. How about your opinion about this resolution?

Thanks.

Comment: Actually I am not clear about your meaning the "open sockets"? The implicitly operations like "process.stdin.resume()"??

Comment: Open sockets would be things like opening a TCP connection or starting a server (in the child).  What are you actually trying to do?  What you're doing now looks like a test, but if you do something real it will most likely cause node.js to keep running.

Comment: Yes, it is just one test, I just want to flush the nodejs working points, such as when we need to resume the stdin explicitly?   the stdin stream of child process is default paused, so "kill" in parent process will "resume" it (child stdin) implicitly? no need to resume it explicitly by child code?

Comment: No, `kill` from the parent won't resume child's stdin.  Those things aren't connected at all.  You have to explicitly resume the child's stdin if that's what you want.

Comment: While why your previous suggestion is working? We did not resume child stdin explicitly in the code, and just adding one setInterval loop, it worked. Could you please give more explanation how the kill in parent interact with the child under this case? Thanks.

Comment: We don't need the child's stdin to be resumed; we just need something to be happening so node doesn't exit.  Consuming stdin is one way, and creating a setInterval is another.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron Dufour. If the stdin is not resumed, how is the signal (kill) passed into the child process? It is handled by operation system? While there should be a channel to pass the signal? Are you clear about the detail mechanism?

Comment: Oh, I see the confusion.  No, signals do not pass over stdin.  The operating system takes care of them.  Signals are defined by the OS, and there's no way to "miss" them by not listening to stdin or something like that.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Aaron Dufour